# Store selected fields from an unordered set on struct to a vector

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector, unordered-set

I have an `unordered_set` that stores the following struct

```
struct match_t{
  size_t score;
  size_t ci;  
};

typedef std::unordered_set<match_t> uniq_t;
```

Now I want to store the elements of `uniq_t myset;` to a vector, but in doing so, I want to copy just the score and not the entire `struct`. I have seen solutions for assigning the elements using `assign` or `back_inserter`. I was wondering how to select just the required fields from the struct. I don't see any parameter in `assign` or `back_inserter` for this purpose.

Should I try overriding `push_back` method for the vector or are there other methods for doing this?

**EDIT 1**
Do I get any performance improvements by using any of these methods instead of looping over the set and assigning the required values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong a simple for loop:

```
std::unordered_set<match_t> myset;
std::vector<std::size_t> myvec;

myvec.reserve(myset.size()); // allocate memory only once

for (const auto& entry : myset)
    myvec.push_back(entry.score);
```

Alternatively, you could use `std::transform` with a custom lambda:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::tranform(myset.cbegin(), myset.cend(), std::back_inserter(myvec),
    [](const auto& entry){ return entry.score; });
```

Another way is to use a range library, e.g. with range-v3

```
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>

std::vector<std::size_t> myvec = myset | ranges::view::transform(&match_t::score);
```

Performance-wise, you can't do anything about the linear pass over all `match_t` objects. The important tweak instead is to minimize the number of allocations. As the size of the resulting `std::vector` is known a priori, a call to `std::vector::reserve` as shown above makes sure that no unnecessary allocation occur.

Comment: Thank you so much. And, I hadn' thought of `reserve` at all - thanks for pointing that out as well.